# Django url rendering

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to build a simple django project but facing troubles with url related changes in case of second app. My first app is app1 and contains login, registration and few other things.

urls.py in app1

```
url(r'^$', views.loginView, name='loginView'),
url(r'^register/$', views.registerationView, name='registerationView'),
url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls'))
```

urls.py in app2

```
url(r'^$', views.homeView, name='homeView'),
```

After logging in, the user is successfully redirected to url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2
```

which is what i want for the register too. Instead, it starts searching for the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/app2
```

which is non existent and gives me 404 error. I want to look for the same url as after login which is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2.
```

This is my views.py file for user register

```
def registerationView(req):
    form = forms.registerForm()
    if req.method=='POST':
        form = forms.registerForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog/')
    return render(req, 'register.html', context={'form': form})
```

Comment: Exactly to what *view* do you want to redirect? How are you redirecting?

Comment: can you try changing **redirect('blog/')** to **redirect('/blog/')?